# Appending strings from checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a string of the `data` attributes (so the chars from M to F)

Attached is my HTML

```
    <div id="days" class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input data-date="M" type="checkbox"> Mon
        </label>
        <label>
            <input data-date="T" type="checkbox"> Tues
        </label>
        <label>
            <input data-date="W" type="checkbox"> Wed
        </label>
        <label>
            <input data-date="R" type="checkbox"> Thurs
        </label>
        <label>
            <input data-date="F" type="checkbox"> Fri
        </label>
    </div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
    $(function(){
        var days = '';
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
            var item=$(this);
            if(item.is(":checked"))
            {
                days += ($('#days label input').data('date'));
            }
        });
    });
```

This is what the program looks like:

[image]

What happens when I click the days, is, I could click the Wednesday checkbox, but only the `M` gets appended. I would click Friday checkbox, and the `M` would be appended.

`M`

`MM`

`MMM`

How do I append the `MTWRF` as well as remove them when they are unclicked?

Comment: use the `.map()` function to get the list of checked checkboxes. try this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pauwtxfd/1/ I am returning an array of checked checkboxes. check the console for output

Comment: Worked perfectly. @Sushil please post this as the answer

Comment: posted my solution @theGreenCabbage. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using the **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** function in jquery.

update your js code like this

```
 $(function() {
     var days = '';
     $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
         var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
             return $(this).data('date');
         }).toArray();
         console.log(searchIDs);
     });

 });
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pauwtxfd/1/)**

Comment: Will accept this one. I also turned the array to string and removed the `,`

Comment: great. yeah you can use it anyway. i used the array incase u might need it somewhere in the code.

Comment: can you please accept this as an answer when you get a chance?

Comment: oh ok. Thank you very much. m glad my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the days variable between clicks and iterate over the inputs each time one changes:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    var days = '';
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) days += $(this).data('date');
    })
    console.log(days)
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1hmdwpsz/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting all the elements, not the current one in the loop. When you read the data, it only selects the first one. Use map()

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    var days = $('#days label input:checked')  //get the checked inputs
        .map( function () {
            return $(this).data('date');  //return the data attribute
        }).get().join("");  //convert to array and than string
    console.log(days);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` instead `'#days label input'` to make reference to the item that was `checked`.

In your code, replace:

```
days += ($('#days label input').data('date'));
```

By:

```
days += ($(this).data('date'));
```

Answer (score 1):

With inputs it's bets to use the value attribute. you could do it like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var days=$(this).map(function(){return this.val()/*or attr('data-date')*/;}).get();
    console.log(days);
});
```

[jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) makes an array of your input's values so it'll look like this `['M','T','W','TH','F']`

You could then use .each to convert this into a string say:

```
days.each(function(i){daysSting+=i});
```